# Drupal quiz permissions per role

Tags: 7, quiz

How can I set Drupal role to a quiz? I will have more quizez and more roles. Each roles has its quiz.

I have a Drupal 7 with quiz module.

I tried different approaches using node acces and acl and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If *node access* and/or *acl* are not sufficient to fit your needs, you should have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, either for D7, or D8. To get an idea of what is possible with this module, checkout [some of my answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a39516%20%5bgroup%5d%20is%3aa) about questions tagged with [group](/questions/tagged/group).

In your case, if you just assign each quiz to an appropriate group, the magic included with the Group module should help you to implement what your question is about.